# Was 0xProject goleveldb/qunit discontinued?

Tags: 0x

I have some projects where the wasm is built on top of the 0xProject goleveldb fork.

Recently one of it's dependencies 'qunit' stopped being found by [pkg.go](https://pkg.go/github.com/0xProject/qunit) and [github](https://github.com/0xProject/qunit). Has it been discontinued?

Answer (score 0):

```
replace github.com/0xProject/qunit => github.com/rusco/qunit v0.0.0-20191017083352-9fa555c2fcc2
```

This replace in go.mod solved the issue for me, hope it can be useful to someone.